# Django Python Invalid Syntax When Deployed on Digitalocean

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a Django project on local machine running on Python 3.10.3
Now I deployed it to a DigitalOcean machine running Ubuntu 20 and Python 3.8.10

When I run the project on local machine there is no issue, but when I do run it on the DO instance, it gives me a syntax error.

Here is the code where it gives me the error:

```
def get_day_by_date(date):
weekday = date.weekday()
match weekday:
    case 0:
        return "Lundi"
    case 1:
        return "Mardi"
    case 2:
        return "Mercredi"
    case 3:
        return "Jeudi"
.......
```

This is the error I get in DO:
[image]

Is it a problem of the Python version?

PS: I have already done pip freeze and installed the exact same requirements on both machines.

Comment: The `match` statement is new in Python 3.10. In previous versions trying to use it will cause a syntax error. In this case a simple `if ... elif ... elif` will work just as well. This particular problem has no need of the power of the `match` statement.

Comment: Okay! No this will need the match because it checks which day of the week (I'm not gonna do 7 if...else statements. Thank you!

Comment: You will have 7 `case` clauses. I fail to see how that is so very much more elegant than one `if`, 5 `elif`s and one `else`. It will take exactly as many lines of code  Even if it is more elegant, in your situation, isn't portability more important than elegance? In any case, you could do this much more crisply by using `weekday` index into a tuple `("Lundi", "Mardi", ... etc,)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution according to @BoarGules is to migrate from Python 3.8 to 3.10 for the `match weekday` to work.